# Adding items to a list view with custom adapter in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-adapter

I am doing a to do list with custom adapter on Android Studio, but I tried to add items and it just stops runnning.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mToDoList;
private EditText mTask;
private Button mAddButton;
private TarefaAdapter adapter;
private List<Tasks> tasks;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mToDoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todo_listView);
mTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

tasks = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
adapter = new TarefaAdapter(tasks, this);

mToDoList.setAdapter(adapter);
mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String content = mTask.getText().toString();
        Tasks task = new Tasks();
        task.setName(content);
        tasks.add(task);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

When it is without the 'adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' the app doesn't stops running, but doesn't add the object to the list neither :(

This is the adapter:

```
public class TarefaAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final List<Tasks> tarefas;
private final Activity act;

public TarefaAdapter(List<Tasks> tarefas, Activity act) {
    this.tarefas = tarefas;
    this.act = act;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tarefas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return tarefas.get(id);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return tarefas.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    Tasks tarefa = tarefas.get(position);

    TextView nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    nome.setText(tarefa.getName());
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show code of your `TarefaAdapter`

Comment: @Phát Phát Yes, i edited